# Boost-button delay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am making a game with a boost button. Of course, just leaving it as enabled would allow the player to tap it constantly. So, I need a 20 second delay before it is possible to push the button again. Also, would it be possible to show this progression on the button, preferably on the button itself?

Answer (score 0):

In the future please try to show what you have tried to solve your problem. However, since you are new I'm going to let it slide once!

This code uses a `NSTimer` that is called once per second. It will fire what ever code you specify for "Boost". It will also disable user interaction on your button until it has been 20 seconds from when the button was pressed at which point it will allow the user to press the button again, and finally, this code displays how many seconds remain until "Boost" can be used again on the `titleLabel` property of your button.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(activateBoost) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)activateBoost
{

    if (myButton.userInteractionEnabled == YES) {
        //Put your Boost code here!


    }

    if ([myButton.titleLabel.text intValue] == 0) {
        [myTimer invalidate];
        [myButton setTitle:@"20" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        myButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }else{
        myButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        int currentTime = [myButton.titleLabel.text intValue];
        int newTime = currentTime - 1;
        myButton.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newTime];
    }

}
```

In order for the above code to work, you will need the declare a `NSTimer` named "myTimer" and a `UIButton` "myButton". You will also need to set the buttons initial text to "20".